# Sporadical weird text while writing on bitmap

Tags: c#, image, text, bitmap, blob

I am looking for some explanation about some weird texts that appears when I write on a bitmap and then upload it to azure blob.

Sometimes when I create an imagem, it comes with theses weird texts where there should be accents. But I recreate it right after and it works...

Here is the imagem gone wrong: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8an62ygys5nnwow/uploaded-image-636488352376069747.png?dl=0

And here is the correct image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3sdsqo3d05skz8/uploaded-image-636493880034621618.png?dl=0

I convert the image url to bitmap:

```
var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = request.GetResponse();
    
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(responseStream);
    
    return bitmap;
}
```

And then I write the text on it:

```
private void AddText(System.Drawing.Image image, string text, int x, int y, int width, int height, int fontSize, Color fontColor, Color borderColor, FontFamily fontFamily, FontStyle fontStyle, StringAlignment horizontalAligment, StringAlignment verticalAligment, bool autoFit, int shadowOffsetX, int shadowOffsetY, Color shadowColor, int? maxHeight, out float finalHeight, out float finalWidth)
    {
        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        var rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat
        {
            Alignment = horizontalAligment,
            LineAlignment = verticalAligment
        };

        var font = new System.Drawing.Font(fontFamily, graphics.DpiY * fontSize / 72, fontStyle);

        if (autoFit)
        {
            font = FindFont(graphics, text, rect.Size, font);
        }

        var hasShadow = shadowOffsetX > 0 && shadowOffsetY > 0;
        var hasMaxHeight = maxHeight != null && maxHeight.Value > 0;

        if (hasShadow)
        {
            var shadowGraphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
            var shadowRect = new Rectangle(x + shadowOffsetX, y + shadowOffsetY, width, height);
            shadowGraphicsPath.AddString(text, fontFamily, (int)fontStyle, font.Size, shadowRect, stringFormat);

            if (hasMaxHeight)
            {
                shadowGraphicsPath = GetTextWithMaxHeight(text, fontFamily, fontStyle, shadowRect, stringFormat, shadowGraphicsPath, font, maxHeight.Value, out float newFontSize);

                font = new System.Drawing.Font(font.FontFamily, newFontSize);
            }
            
            graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(shadowColor), shadowGraphicsPath);
            graphics.Flush();
            shadowGraphicsPath.Dispose();
        }

        var graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
        
        graphicsPath.AddString(text, fontFamily, (int)fontStyle, font.Size, rect, stringFormat);

        if (hasMaxHeight && !hasShadow)
        {
            graphicsPath = GetTextWithMaxHeight(text, fontFamily, fontStyle, rect, stringFormat, graphicsPath, font, maxHeight.Value, out float newFontSize);
        }

        graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(borderColor), graphicsPath);
        graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(fontColor), graphicsPath);

        finalHeight = graphicsPath.GetBounds().Height;
        finalWidth = graphicsPath.GetBounds().Width;

        graphics.Flush();
        graphicsPath.Dispose();
    }
```

And then I upload to azure blob

```
var container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(_imageConfiguration.BlobContainer);

        var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference($"uploaded-image-{DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Ticks}.png");

        using (var imageStream = ConvertToStream(image, ImageFormat.Png))
        {
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(imageStream);

            var uri = blockBlob.Uri;

            return uri;
        }
```

Can someone help me find an explanation for this?

Comment: The font you're using does not have the specified chars or the default culture is not the correct and the special chars (.Â, Ì and so on) aren't being converted correctly. If the string comes from the web use UTF8 encoding to transfer the data.

Comment: Also the font style changes between bold and not bold. In `if (hasMaxHeight)` you create a new font without specifying the font style. I.e., depending whether the max height has been rechaed or not, the font might be bold or not.

Comment: The string I get from the database. I download the font... Could that be it? But is this error intermittent?

Comment: Images are broken...